# How to use macros with parameters inside a \newenvironment?

Tags: environments

I would like to define a new environment that changes the section titles via `\titleformat`. Obviously I have to "escape" the `#1` somehow, so it is not considered to be an (undeclared) parameter to `local_format_env`, but a parameter to `\titleformat`. How do I do that?

(Omitting the `[explicit]` option to `titlesec` is not an option due to constraints not present in the example for simplicity of presentation.)

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newenvironment{local_format_env}{
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large}{}{0pt}{#1} % <-- needs excaping
}{
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{#1}         % <-- needs escaping
}

\begin{document}

\section{Global Format}

\begin{local_format_env}
\section{Local Format}
\end{local_format_env}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a case of replacing `#1` with `##1`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newenvironment{local_format_env}{
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large}{}{0pt}{##1} % <-- needs excaping
}{
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{##1}         % <-- needs escaping
}

\begin{document}

\section{Global Format}

\begin{local_format_env}
\section{Local Format}
\end{local_format_env}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although I'm beginning to wonder whether just not using the `explicit` option wouldn't make more sense?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, it is not an option. The *actual* formatting done by the *real* document is somewhat more involved than the one in my example here. Probably most importantly, one of the formattings involved *doesn't* print the section title (by *omitting* the `#1`), which would be somewhat difficult without `[explicit]`. (Well, I guess I could set it in white, but...)